# KIE Drools Workbench not show all Menu Option

Tags: gwt, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have a problem with the "KIE Drools Workbench" v6.0.1.Final, when enter to Workbench, the browser show me the next error **"ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml module file."** and not show all the menu option, only show "Authoring" and "Deployment".

I have install to addons GWT to browser

This problem occurs in Chrome and firefox browser, my SO is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

The complete message error is that :

''ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml module file.
The compile time user.agent value (gecko1_8) does not match the runtime user.agent value (safari). Expect more errors.''

And the my browser is Chrome,  I check all *.gwt.xml files to include gecko1_8, and all file in this.

Help me !!

PDT : Sorry for my english , I speak spanish

Comment: Hmmm.. can you explain what are you trying to do? how are you installing KIE Workbench?? Are you running in hosted mode? did you compile the workbench yourself?
We need more background to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, I need install jbpm-console-ng war in jboss, to show all the menu option. And not kie-wb